# Upload files to S3 using AWS S3 static web hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have been looking at options for uploading files to S3. One option which we are looking at using S3 static web hosting. In this option we will have a page which I am trying to write a simple Index.html page with a upload option. I set the following Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following is the CORS setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The following is the code in Index.html

```
<html>
<header><title>Hello World</title></header>
<body>
Hello world

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try accessing my s3 bucket with the webhosting URI, I am getting the page and when I try to upload the document I am getting the following error:

```
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: action_page.php
RequestId: <requestid>
HostId: <hostid>
An Error Occurred While Attempting to Retrieve a Custom Error Document

Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: error.html
```

if I add the error.html page its showing my error page.

Now is my thinking to use S3 webhosting to upload files to the bucket without any coding is the right way? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You can't run any PHP files on an S3 static website - that requires a back-end server, and your form is trying to post to 'action_page.php'.

That simply won't work.

Here is just one example of how you might proceed:

> In this example, a simple HTML page provides a browser-based application for creating photo albums in an Amazon S3 bucket into which you can upload photos. The application lets you delete photos and albums that you add.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html